# Breadcrumbs stop working on a specific template file

Tags: query-posts, breadcrumb

I'm working on a theme and i use dimox's breadcrumbs to display breadcrumbs in the footer, so far so good, works almost flawlessly

BUT

there's one template file where i use 2 loops and i'm guessing this is what screws with the breadcrumbs... but i couldn't put my finger on it exactly...

here's the code:

```
<div class="span-24">



<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $parent_title = $post->post_title; ?>
<?php $parent_content = $post->post_content; ?>
<?php $parent = $post->ID; ?>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>


<div id="preview">
    <img id="previewImg" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/images/spacer.png" alt="" />
</div>

<h1><?php echo $parent_title; ?></h1>

<div class="proj_list">     
    <ul id="previewUL">
    <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=15&post_type=page&post_parent='.$parent); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>   
    <?php $image_thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image-thumb', true); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), medium, false, '' ); echo $src[0]; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="">  
    <?php print($parent_content);?>
</div>

<script  type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('img#previewImg').animate({opacity: 0}, 0 );
    jQuery('#previewUL li a').each(
        function( intIndex ){

        jQuery(this).hover(
            function(){
                var imgurl = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
                jQuery('img#previewImg').attr('src', imgurl);
                jQuery('img#previewImg').clearQueue();
                jQuery('img#previewImg').animate({opacity: 0}, 0 );
                jQuery('img#previewImg').animate({opacity: 1}, 250 );
            },
            function(){
                jQuery('img#previewImg').animate({opacity: 0}, 250 );
            });

        }
    );
});
</script>

</div><!--/span-24-->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Take a look at previewUL ...

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot, but what happens if you add in a `wp_reset_query()` call?

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my question! can you please point out WHERE should i add the call?

Comment: Somewhere between the closing of the loop for your second query, and the start of the breadcrumbs output.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the second loops with this code:

```
<?php $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null; $wp_query = new WP_Query('showposts=15&post_type=page&post_parent='.$parent); ?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

/* your content */

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>
```

Comment: Yay, it works! thanks a million... would you be kind and gimme a lil' explanation of what was i doing wrong and how your solution remedied that? I admit a don't fully understand that...

Comment: This is an alternate method to resetting the query via `wp_reset_query()`. In this case, the original query is dumped into a variable, a new query is generated and output, and then the original query is restored. Thus, the original query (i.e. the original data contained in the `$wp_query` global) will again be available when the breadcrumbs function expects it to be available.